# didRangeBeaconRegion method gives repeated beacon device in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cllocationmanager

i'm new to ibeacon apps,in my app i need to find the iBeacon device.here i'm having three beacon device.i find the device by the didRangeBeaconRegion method.i showed these detected beacon in a table view.
My problem is this method calls every seconds so my value having repeated beacons and many numbers rows.

how to show the three beacons details only in the table view.
i searched in the android app it shows only that three beacons only.

below is my code,

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{ 
    if(beacons.count>0)
    {
 CLBeacon *beacon=[[CLBeacon alloc]init];
    beacon=[beacons firstObject];
        [uuidArr addObject:beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString];
        [minArr addObject:beacon.minor];
        [majArr addObject:beacon.major];
        [rssiArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)beacon.rssi]];
        [distanceArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f m",beacon.accuracy]];

        NSString *proxStr;
        if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown)
        {
            proxStr = @"Unknown";
        }
        else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate)
        {
            proxStr= @"Immediate";
        }
        else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear) {
           proxStr = @"Near";
        }
        else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar) {
            proxStr = @"Far";
        }
        [proxArr addObject:proxStr];
    }
    else
    {

    }

    [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the first object only to the beacon so you get the first beacon Value in the Beacons Array  i.e if you have 4 beacon device means you get the first beacon only & didRangeBeacons method calls every second in that your adding the first object to your array like uuidArr,minArr like that,

Now Solution is:

1.remove all the Value in array above the if Condition.

2.Don't take the first object only.

3.put one for loop to add the list of devices.

code:

```
    [uuidArr removeAllObjects];
    [minArr removeAllObjects];
    [majArr removeAllObjects];
    [rssiArr removeAllObjects];
    [distanceArr removeAllObjects];
    [proxArr removeAllObjects];

    if(beacons.count>0)
    {
        CLBeacon *beacon=[[CLBeacon alloc]init];
        for(int i=0;i<beacons.count;i++)
        {
            beacon=beacons[i];
            [uuidArr addObject:beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString];
            [minArr addObject:beacon.minor];
            [majArr addObject:beacon.major];
            [rssiArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)beacon.rssi]];
            [distanceArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f m",beacon.accuracy]];

        NSString *proxStr;
        if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown)
        {
            proxStr = @"Unknown";
        }
        else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate)
        {
            proxStr= @"Immediate";
        }
        else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear) {
           proxStr = @"Near";
        }
        else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar) {
            proxStr = @"Far";
        }
        [proxArr addObject:proxStr];
        }
    }
```

now you get the number of devices you having.i hope this is help to you

Comment: as you said first value only you get from the beacons array,but i'm getting all three beacons.

Comment: yes you can get all your beacons values, for ex. you have A B C beacons first time it get the  A C B then C B A then C A B then B A C like this you can get the beacon value so get get it. first you log the Beacons Array then you easily understand.